# Create latLngBounds based on zoom level and a center point

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I have a list of features/polygons that I need to run an operation on based on the maps bounding box relative to the feature, without moving the map.

To further explain my problem I can give an example of how I could do this if moving the map around wasn't an issue:

```
features.forEach(function (feature) {
    var bbox,
        ne,
        sw,
        fBounds,
        zoom,
        mBounds;

    bbox = feature.geometry.bbox;
    sw = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0]);
    ne = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2]);
    fBounds = L.latLngBounds(sw, ne);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    mBounds = map.getBounds();
    zoom = map.getZoom();
    //Execute operation based on mBounds and zoom
}
```

I have tested a lot and this is the closest thing I have to a working code snippet:

```
        var self = this,
            bbox,
            sw,
            ne,
            bounds,
            zoom,
            swPoint,
            nePoint,
            center,
            factor,
            dw,
            dh,
            cpx;

        bbox = feature.geometry.bbox;
        sw = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0]);
        ne = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2]);
        bounds = L.latLngBounds(sw, ne);
        zoom = self.map.getBoundsZoom(bounds, false); //maxZoom?
        swPoint = self.map.project(bounds.getSouthWest(), zoom),
        nePoint = self.map.project(bounds.getNorthEast(), zoom),
        center = self.map.unproject(swPoint.add(nePoint).divideBy(2), zoom);

        factor = self.map.options.crs.scale(zoom) / 8388608;
        dw = self.map.getSize().x / 2*factor;
        dh = self.map.getSize().y / 2*factor;
        cpx = self.map.options.crs.latLngToPoint(center, zoom);            

        return {
            ne: self.map.options.crs.pointToLatLng(L.point(cpx.x + dw, cpx.y - dh, false), zoom),
            sw: self.map.options.crs.pointToLatLng(L.point(cpx.x - dw, cpx.y + dh, false), zoom),
            center: center,
            zoom: zoom
        }

        //Execute operation based on returned object, repeat for every feature
```

This 'works' but it doesn't give the same result as the first code snippet (i.e. the results are wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet worked for me, in case anyone else should have the same question:

```
var self = this,
    bbox,
    sw,
    ne,
    bounds,
    zoom,
    center;

bbox = feature.geometry.bbox;
sw = L.latLng(bbox[1], bbox[0]);
ne = L.latLng(bbox[3], bbox[2]);
bounds = L.latLngBounds(sw, ne);
zoom = self.map.getBoundsZoom(bounds, false); //maxZoom?
sw = self.map.project(bounds.getSouthWest(), zoom),
ne = self.map.project(bounds.getNorthEast(), zoom),
center = self.map.unproject(sw.add(ne).divideBy(2), zoom);

bounds = self.map.getPixelBounds(center, zoom),
sw = self.map.unproject(b2.getBottomLeft()),
ne = self.map.unproject(b2.getTopRight());

return new L.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
```